# PubNub subscribe message callback not firing

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, pubnub

I'm having issues getting PubNub's subscribe message handler to fire. I'm working on a web client that will listen for messages from mobile apps. Up until recently, this code worked fine. I could send a message from my phone and see the web app get auto-updated. But in the last few days, the web app is no longer getting updated.

It's an Angular app that I've been writing in CoffeeScript. I have a `MessageService` that handles all the bootstrapping for PubNub. The `subscribe` method of my service is passed an entity `id` arg to set as the channel name to listen on, and passes a function reference via the `messageHandler` argument.

```
angular.module('exampleApp').service 'MessageService', ($http, $interval) ->
  pubnub = null
  subscribePromise = null

  config =
    subscribe_key: 'demo'

  # Sanity check. This gets triggered upon connection with the correct 
  # channel name/entity id.
  connectionHandler = ->
    _.forOwn arguments, (arg) -> console.log arg

  return {
    getChats: (id) ->
      # Calls an API to fetch all of the chat messages. These aren't transmitted over
      # PubNub because we do other fun things to adhere to HIPAA compliance.
      return $http.get 'path/to/api/endpoint/' + id
    subscribe: (id, messageHandler) ->
      pubnub = pubnub or PUBNUB.init config
      pubnub.subscribe({
        channel: id
        message: (data) ->
          if not not subscribePromise
            $interval.cancel subscribePromise
            subscribePromise = null
          messageHandler data
        connect: connectionHandler
      })

      # Interval-based workaround to function in spite of PubNub issue
      subscribePromise = $interval messageHandler, 10000
  }
```

Here's an example of the `messageHandler` implementation in one of my controllers.

```
angular.module('exampleApp').controller 'MessageCtrl', (MessageService) ->
  $scope.messageId = 'some entity id'

  # This message handler never gets fired, despite passing it to pubnub.subscribe
  onMessageUpdated = (data) ->
    console.log data
    MessageService.getChats($scope.messageId).then (messages) -> $scope.messages = messages

  MessageService.subscribe $scope.messageId, onMessageUpdated
```

Like I mentioned, this code was working not long ago, but out of the blue, the message handler stopped firing at all. Haven't touched it in more than a month. The thing that's driving me nuts is that I can open up the dev console in PubNub and watch the messages come in from the phones, but for some reason, that message handler never seems to get called.

I'm using the "edge" version of pubnub.js, so I'm wondering if there was some recent update that broke my implementation. Anything else you folks can see that I may be missing or doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

// Edit

Just a quick update. I've tried rolling back as far as 3.5.47 and still no change in behavior. I coded a quick workaround using Angular's `$interval` service to allow the app to at least function while I get this issue figured out. Updated code example above w/ relevant changes.

Comment: The quick fix may be to use a version of the PubNub.js file that works for you like: `<script src=https://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub-3.6.5.min.js ></script>` perhaps!  :-)

Comment: Hi Again!  Let us know if this works out for you by setting a specific Version ID of the PubNub JS SDK.

Comment: I thought I tried 3.6.5 of your API, but I'll give it another go and let you know how it works out.

Comment: Cool!  Continue to decrement the version until you find the right one.  3.6.5 should work.

Comment: I went as far back as 3.5.47 and no luck. I tried different versions on the [JS SDK page](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/javascript-sdk.html) and still no luck.

Comment: Strange!  This sounds like it could be a deeper issue.  Can you contact support@pubnub.com to continue our investigation.

Comment: Will do. Should have some time in the next day or so to get in touch. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: JasonOffutt, did you ever get resolution on this issue? If so, please share.

Comment: No. Our resolution was to not use PubNub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick update. After moving on to some other tasks and circling back to this after a year or so, we decided to take another stab at the problem. The interval-based polling was working fine for our initial implementation as described above, but we now have need for a more robust set of features.

Anyway, we ended up grabbing the latest stable version of the JS client (3.7.21), and so far it appears to have fixed our issue.